# Alternative ways to display an activity on a secondary display in Android

Tags: android, performance, android-dialog, multiple-monitors

Does anyone know of an alternative way to display an activity on a second display? The presentation approach seems hacky to me. It is basically a dialog but we are telling it to display full screen on a different monitor.

I have an Android device with two video outputs. I am currently using the  Presentation Class to display an Activity on my secondary display. My concern is that the hardware is treating it all as one screen, since a presentation is essentially a Dialog, and is trying to render all the content on one chip instead of utilizing the two that it has. The reason for my concern is video playback is really bad as soon as I start playing videos on both displays.

This may be too low level of a question but if someone knowledgeable on the issue could chime in I would be very grateful, or point me in the direction of someone who could help, or even places I could look for answers.

Comment: It sounds like your problem is much more with the hardware and the port of Android to that hardware, rather than with `Presentation` itself. What is your evidence that the problem is specific to `Presentation`?

Comment: I don't actually have any hard evidence beside that when I play a high bit rate video at lets say 30MBps 1920x1080 It plays great. When I switch to displaying a video on each output with low bit rate videos at 10MBps 1920x1080 you can see frames being dropped. The **theory** I have is that the presentation is being treated as part of the same output as the main activity therefore everything is being rendered by one chip. If that makes sense.

Comment: I am assuming that by "one chip" you are referring to one GPU. Most Android devices only have one GPU, and I don't know to what extent Android itself is in position to support more than one GPU. You are welcome to experiment with low-level `WindowManager` stuff, as I did in [my `PresentationService` class](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-presentation/blob/master/presentation/src/main/java/com/commonsware/cwac/preso/PresentationService.java). I do not expect that this will change your results.

Comment: Oh ya by chip I mean't the IPU. The hardware I am using is i.MX6 based and basically I am skeptical that the presentation is being handed off to the right IPU. I will take a look at the link you provided.